# Finding out the physical path of an ISAPI dll

Tags: delphi, iis, dll, isapi

I'm converting a Delphi ISAPI dll to work better on IIS 7.0 and 7.5. The ISAPI used to read its configuration from the registry but I wanted to convert that to using the web.config file in the same folder.

It worked fine with CGI but the ISAPI is another matter. I'm using `GetModuleFileName` to get the path of the module and, of course, it's giving me back the path of the IIS worker process (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv).

Is there a way to get the physical path of the ISAPI dll itself ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using this function and works great.

```
function GetDllName: string;
var
  pName: PChar;
begin
  GetMem(pName, 200);
  windows.GetModuleFileName(HInstance, pName, 200);
  Result := string(pName);
  FreeMem(pName);
end;
```

Comment: That is the function to use, but you can do it much easier: `DllName := GetModuleName(HInstance)`