# IIS and Delphi - Get the application folder inside ISAPI

Tags: delphi, iis, isapi

When running an ISAPI application on IIS, if we call `ParamStr(0)` or `Application.ExeName` inside our ISAPI we will get the folder that IIS is installed (C:\windows...).

Is there any way of getting the folder path which contains my ISAPI instead of IIS's application folder?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041492/finding-out-the-physical-path-of-an-isapi-dll should I say exactly duplicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ISAPI application is a library (DLL), therefore you can use this approach to get its folder:

> ExtractFilePath(GetModuleName(HInstance))

Use `ExtractFileDir()` instead of `ExtractFilePath()` if you don't need the last backslash.

Rationale: According to Delphi docs,

> Several variables declared in the System unit are of special interest to those programming libraries. ... During a library's lifetime, HInstance contains its instance handle.

Using GetModuleName() you get that DLL's file name. ParamStr(0), on the other hand, contains the name of the main EXE where this DLL has been loaded to.

Comment: Yeah .. it seems to work, but I am getting some characters in the beginning of the path that was not supposed to be there, like `\\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\`.

Comment: You can go ahead and use this path as is. It will work for all intents and purposes. You can also try to use ExpandFileName() and see if it changes the path to the more usual variant.